# Mysql - Multiple incorrect date format stored

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

I am working with data where the developer prior to me has been lazy and not stored the date in a set format.  Its in as varchar and not a datetime.  Needless to say its left me needing to sort the data.

Its in two formats

```
1) {dd}/{mm}/{yyyy} {hh}:{mm}
2) {dd}.{mm}.{yyyy} {hh}:{mm}
```

I would like to ensure that it is always returned in the mysql dateformat.  The query below will get the first one.

```
SELECT 
  str_to_date( a.rentalstart, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i' ),
  a.* 
FROM 
  jupiter1.table a
ORDER by createtime DESC
```

How would I combine the two?  I would also need it default to a normal mysql datetime if it matches.

`{yyyy}-{mm}-{dd} {hh}:{mm}:{ss}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.rentalstart LIKE "%/%/% %:%"
            THEN str_to_date( a.rentalstart, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i' )
            WHEN a.rentalstart LIKE "%.%.% %:%"
            THEN str_to_date( a.rentalstart, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i' )
            ELSE CAST(a.rentalstart AS DATETIME)
       END AS rentalstart_good,
       a.*
FROM ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer this worked.  I particulary like the use of CAST

Comment: @Robbo_UK: Actually, the `CAST()` is necessary to ensure that the `rentalstart_good` column in the resultset is of a temporal datatype - else it will be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple do `REPLACE`. It will turn all records in the format `{dd}.{mm}.{yyyy} {hh}:{mm}` and convert it to `DateTime` data type.

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(a.rentalstart, '/', '.'), '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i') newDate,
        a.*
FROM    jupiter1.table a
ORDER   BY newDate DESC
```

Comment: "*I would also need it default to a normal mysql datetime if it matches `{yyyy}-{mm}-{dd} {hh}:{mm}:{ss}`*"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  str_to_date( replace(replace(a.rentalstart, '.', '-'), '/', '-'), if(a.rentalstart like '%-%-%-%', '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i', '%d-%m-%Y %k:%i' )),
  a.* 
FROM 
  jupiter1.table a
ORDER by createtime DESC
```

Does this solve your problem?

 Edited to include your default condition also